# The background to locate for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

We because of the functional requirements of the application of rules in 30 minutes to the server upload a local position, so I used in the project background, but submits to apple for review has been rejected,Then I shall, in accordance with the apple to add their prompt solution in the description of application of power loss of battery and so on, but still with the reason to refuse me, I really can't understand, what a great god met this kind of problem?

Reason:

> 2.16 Details
>
> Your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file but does not declare any features that require persistent location. Apps that declare support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file must have features that require persistent location.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app to include features that require the persistent use of real-time location updates while the app is in the background. Please also add the following battery use disclaimer in your Application Description:
>   "Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life."
>
> If your app does not require persistent real-time location updates, please remove the "location" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key. You may wish to use the significant-change location service or the region monitoring location service if persistent real-time location updates are not required for your app features.

Comment: Based on your decription Apple refused background location services for two reasons: 1) you need to add the disclaimer for battery consumption and 2) (more importantly) the functionality of your application does not need background lcoation services in Apple's opinion and in their view your app is collecting info in the background without real functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO.

Your post is an unintelligible mess. You need to craft clear English language sentences that explain why you need background location services, and you also need to add language that warns the user that your app will reduce the user's battery life, as they explained to you.

It sounds to me like you are saying that your app needs to send updated location information to your server every 30 minutes even when it is running in the background.

If so, you need to explain that, and explain *why* you need to do that.

I gather that English is not your native language. You might need help from somebody who is fluent in both English and your language to translate your explanation so you can submit it to Apple.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, English is not my native language, so it is likely to be the content of the reviewers can't understand my explanation, I'll revise my application description submitted to apple again, thank you.